# When practicing parallelism, do I need to include the "to" in infinitives?

Tags: verbs, infinitives, parallelism

For example:

1. He likes to eat, sleep and play.
2. He likes to eat, to sleep and to play.

Which of these sentences is parallel? Are they BOTH parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these are correct and both of these use parallel structure.

When using the infinitive form (to + base verb) with parallel structure, you can either have to on the first verb only or on every verb.

The important things to remember are:

Don't put 'to' on more than one verb unless you put it on all of them. E.g. "He likes to eat, to sleep and play" - This makes it seems like 'to sleep and play' is a single verb which is clearly not correct in this situation.

Don't mix infinitive with a different verb form. E.g. "He like to eat, sleeping and to play". This is grammatically incorrect and sounds dreadful.

Further reading: [Owlcation](https://owlcation.com/humanities/Parallelism-in-Writing-Sentences-with-Lists)